# Low Quality Posts Review Queue: What is the criteria for automatic deletion?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

I recently flagged an answer as NAA and found that the flag was disputed.  Looking at the timeline, I saw that the post entered the queue and gained 4 Recommend Deletion votes, 3 Looks OK votes, and 1 Delete vote.

If this post gained more Delete/Recommend Deletion votes than Looks OK votes, why was it not deleted?  What is the threshold for automatic deletion in the Low Quality Posts Review Queue?

For clarification, this particular answer had a net score of 0 (+2/-2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes 6 delete recommendations to delete the item, and 3 "Looks OK" votes to kick it out of the queue.

Comment: Alternatively, it takes 3 "delete" votes, but in practice this rarely happens since most reviewers won't have the delete bad answers privilege at 20k.

Comment: For completeness, the exact rules are laid [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092), under the "Proposed changes" section.